# Running Skype 2.1 beta with KDE 4.3

Tags: linux, skype, kde-4, pulse-audio

I'm trying the new Skype Linux Beta ( Skype 2.1.0.47 ) with KDE 4.3 on OpenSUSE 11.1 . Sound works just fine for:

- Amarok
- SMplayer
- Firefox (flash)

but I get absolutely no output from Skype. Please note that this new version is supposed to work with PulseAudio, so the sound devices are all "PulseaAudio server(local)".

My PulseAudio version is pulseaudio-0.9.14-2.2.1 and I've tried KDE with both the GStreamer and Xine backends.

---

Update: I get audio with PulseAudio 0.9.15, but I can't get voice capture to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had problems with Skype and pulseaudio on Ubuntu 9.04.  There's a wiki about how to configure pulseaudio [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio) for Ubuntu but should work for OpenSUSE.
Basically, you have to:
- launch pavucontrol, switch to recording tab
- launch skype & call Skype test lady
- wait for "Skype: Input" meter to show up
- Right click on it and choose "Move Stream" to your mic
- Repeat for playback if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will go throught with it once pavucontrol stops segfaulting.

Answer (score 0):

for every software you may be have to reconfigure your sound controls ...

and for skype, some peoples ditch PulseAudio to return to just oss/alsa ...

I hope for better sound control on linux and earcandy is a software maded as a test of new implementations that could be maded to pulseaudio, is worth trying it also ...

Comment: This is the new Skype Beta for Linux, based off Pulse Audio.